# Why is the destructor called multiple times when a class object containing a pointer member is passed by reference? How do I correct this?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, reference, destructor

I have a class of the form

```
class A
{
    int **a;
    //other members  
}
```

In some function, I pass an object of class A, say, `obj`, by reference

```
void func(A &o); //function declaration
```

and

```
func(std::ref(obj)); //function call
```

However, I got the following error - [double free or corruption (!prev)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14063791/5987698)

According to the linked question, this is because the destructor is called multiple times for the pointer member, a consequence of the copy constructor being called multiple times when copying, causing an attempted deallocation of memory already deallocated. However, as I am passing the complete object by reference, why should this happen? Shouldn't the address of the whole object be simply copied?

Suggestions for implementing a copy constructor in the form given in the above link and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/5987698) won't help as they involve allocating a fresh amount of memory whenever the object is copied, whereas I would like to pass the object, and as a result the pointer member, by reference.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28004561/5987698) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7681571/5987698), potential duplicates,but they didn't solve my problem.

Based on a few other answers, I also tried implementing a destructor as

```
~A()
{
    delete[] a;
}
```

or

```
~A()
{
    if(a)
    {
        delete[] a;
    }
}
```

but neither solved the problem.

Comment: Somewhere in the code you haven't shown, you are passing your object by value, so a copy is made. If you'd like further help, show [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Prohibit copy ctor and assignment operator and compiler will tell you where  you copy data by value.

Comment: @Slava How do I do that?

Comment: C++11 - delete them, pre C++11 make them private, read the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077143/disable-copy-constructor

Comment: @Slava thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try `A(A const&)=delete;` and `A(A&&o):a(o.a){a=nullptr;}`.  This deletes your copy ctor and writes a non-allocating move ctor.

A deleted copy ctor will give you compile-time errors if you try to copy an instance of your class.  As in your case this results in a crash at destruction, it seems like a good idea.

That move ctor will let you return instances of your class safely from functions, so long as the return value is implicitly or explicitly (`std::move`) moved-from.

Also consider

```
A& operator=(A&&o) { 
  if (this==&o) return *this; 
  std::swap(a,o.a); 
  delete[] o.a; 
  o.a=nullptr; 
  return *this; 
}
A& operator=(A const&o)=delete;
```

Which lets you assign to `A` from another moved-from `A`.

The fact you should deal with move/copy assign/construct when you write a destructor is called the rule of five.

The fact you should avoid writing any of them is called the rule of zero.

To avoid writing them, replace your `a` with a `unique_ptr<int[]>`.  Now it generates your move operations and destructor for you and deletes your copy operations, all automaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I had been returning an object of the class from a function, which invoked the copy constructor. I had overlooked the fact that the object would be passed by value.

The comment by [@IgorTandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) answers the question partly, to the extent that it confirmed that there was no reason for the problem I observed to happen except that I had overlooked a pass by value happening somewhere.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077164/5987698) from the link provided in [@Slava's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432358/slava)  comment is highly useful for finding out the source of the problem.